# Laravel Reset Password Error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I've previously set up password resets with Laravel 5.6 and the password reset links were working fine, but now it suddenly gives me a RuntimeException ( `Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: /var/www/{domain}/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources)`) when I click on the "Send Password Reset Link" button. I double checked my mail settings in my .env file and everything is normal, but I'm absolutely clueless why this is now giving me an error on both the aforementioned site (where it worked fine 7 days ago) and on a new site I'm working on. 
It's even adding the token to the database, but isn't sending the Email and is giving that error right after I click the button, instead of redirecting with a status message like it should be doing.

Does anybody have any idea why this might have happened and what I can do to go about fixing it?

Note: I'm using zoho with the following settings in the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD={hidden}
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: Share all steps that you follow to setup?

Comment: `php artisan make:auth` is basically all I did for the new site, the other site is an extension of these functions to allow for multiple users, but still functions just the same.